# reseting start_date of an existing airflow dag

Tags: airflow-scheduler

can I reset start_date of an existing airflow dag without changing its name? I have dag running currently in airflow .

Answer (score 0):

You should never change start_date without changing the dag name. Doing so will lead to unpredictable results. And changing dag name is also safe for your operations as when the dag name changed, the dag under old name will immediately stop running and new dag will initiate in seconds. As it should never happen that an old name dag existing while the new name dag exists simultaneously if you simply change the dag name then save. Especially, it will be highly safe if you are using git to sync your code and always change the dag name when start_date and interval changed.